# @ElementCollection field setter does not work

Tags: java, jpa, setter

I have Entity bean with list annotated with `@ElementCollection`:

```
...

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "MAP_REGION_MANAGER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID"), schema="CALC")
private List<RegionManager> regionManager;

...
```

I try to set value to this field and then save the entire entity to DB. I set value:

```
emp.setRegionManager(new ArrayList<RegionManager>());
```

but the value of field `regionManager` is still *NULL* after the setter. I have several fields with `@ElementCollection` annotation in this entity, and they all behave like this - setter does not set the value. I can't understand what is the problem..

Comment: One checking: is MAP_REGION_MANAGER defined as an entity at persistence.xml?

Comment: No it is not. But it worked earlier. There was a small refactoring, but nothing was changed that could cause this problem, I'll try to add it to persistence.xml now and check again.

Comment: Adding MAP_REGION_MANAGER to persistence.xml didn't help

Comment: Is your entity recovering values in it's List<RegionManager> regionManager attribute or comes empty after a query? Check RegionManager to be right annotated pointing to it's related database table, add the class to the persistence.xml and try it again

Comment: Tried your recomendations - does not work. I tried to map the field using @OnetoMany, it does not work too. If I remove the persistence annotations, setter sets the value. So persisted lists fileds are not set by setter. I absolutely dont' understand it..

Comment: Which JPA framework are you using? And how do you know that `regionManager` is `null`? Are you checking in the debugger, are you logging the value from inside the instance or are you logging `getRegionManager()` from the outside?

Comment: Reached this point, perhaps it would be useful if you would copy the Entity Bean class, the RegionManager entity and the persistence.xml